# Где здесь ошибка?(язык c#)

Tags: c#

```
  Console.Write("Введите натуральное число больше 2. n= ");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Введите натуральное число k= ");
        string k = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        bool g = Convert.ToBoolean(n);
        bool h = Convert.ToBoolean(k);
        int u = Convert.ToInt32(k);
        int i = 3;
        var a = 1;
        var b = 1;
        int f = 0;
        if (u < 3)
        {
            f = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 3; h; i++) {
                f = a + b;
                a = b;
                b = f;
            }

        }

            Console.Write(k, "-е число Фибоначчи = " + f);
            Console.Write("Первые ", n, " членов Фибоначчи:");

            Console.Write("1 1");
            var s = 2;
        for (i=3; g; i++) 
        {
            f = a + b;
            Console.Write(f +" ");
            s = s + f;
            a = b;
            b = f;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("Сумма =" + s);
        if (s % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Верно что сумма четная");
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Не верно что сумма четная");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();\
```

Comment: флаги h, g не меняю своего значения. Поэтому все циклы будут бесконечными

Comment: Здесь много ошибок, конкретизируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Console.ReadKey();\
> ```

Как минимум, здесь.

Comment: а в чем именно здесь ошибка?

Comment: @VIRUS, в ```\```.

Comment: это не помогло(

Comment: @VIRUS, печалька.